# Why am I getting Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT even though it exists?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am getting error

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
> Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
> org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for

Even thought [this](https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/springframework/spring-core/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/) https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/springframework/spring-core/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/ exists

Here is my POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<groupId>com.pluralsight</groupId>
<artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>15</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
            
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshot</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/</url>
        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        <releases><enabled>false</enabled> </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Also check https://spring.io/blog/2020/10/29/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-fall-and-winter-2020

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use https in your repository declaration.